# ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail return null bitmap for mp4 file

Tags: android, video, bitmap

When I get bitmap for mp4 file with: `ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(mediaFile.getAbsolutePath(), MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);` return null

Comment: could you solve this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this, May be you media file path was wrong. Use below method you will get exact path. Its working for me

```
 Bitmap thumb = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(getPath(outputFileUri),
                        MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);

photo_Img.setImageBitmap(thumb);

/**
 * Get file path
 */
public static String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
Cursor cursor = context.managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

Comment: I tried your method. Then I got a problem.`Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(Uri.fromFile(mediaFile), proj, null, null, null);` `cursor` return `null`

Comment: It returns null..any solution for it?

Comment: Deprecated in api api 29

Answer (score 4):

I think you must set  requires permission in AndroidManifest `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Answer (score 2):

```
File file = new File(filepath);
Bitmap bitmap = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(file.getAbsolutePath(), MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.FULL_SCREEN_KIND);
```

Answer (score 1):

From android docs:

> **public static Bitmap createVideoThumbnail (String filePath, int kind)**
>
> Create a video thumbnail for a video. May return null if the video is corrupt or the format is not supported.

Hence, I guess you need to re-check the mp4 file.

Comment: what do you mean corrupt? My mp4 file can play in windows.

Comment: If the video is not corrupt, then I see only one reason for this behavior. Check the file path and ensure it's correct. It returns null bitmap in case path is wrong.

Comment: As you can see, I get the path with `mediaFile.getAbsolutePath()`, am I wrong?

Comment: I really did use another video, and it worked. But the rest (I tried 5 different videos) didn't work.